# JAXB marshal any xml to a String [Marshal mutiple tags at once to a String]

Tags: java, xml, string, jaxb

My requirement: I want to make a JAXB class for below xml

```
<Request>
 <Data>mydata</Data>
 <Details>
---Any XML content(utf-8)---
 </Details>
</Request>
```

any xml content can be like B and so on

**What I WANT**

I want Any xml content in string object (HOW DO I DO THIS)(How do we marshal it to a single String object?)

Say Any Xml content is

```
<A>
 <B>
  value
 </B>
</A>
```

I want it to bind to String object as `<A><B>value<B><A>`

Comment: and your actual question is?

Comment: what is the actual question?

Comment: Oops
How do we marshal it to a single String object?